# How to Override the default method of object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I hope someone can answer this that has a good deep understanding of Python :)
surely solution for below query is fully python based(2.x, 3.x),

My directory structure looks like:

> mywebapp/
>
> ```
> __init__.py
> views.py
> flaskutil.py run.py
> ```

**init**.py:

```
from parent.mywebapp.flaskutil import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

If run.py on top of webapp directory and its working as expected.

```
from parent.mywebapp import app    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

as shown above app object/instance of Flask class so it has default method errorhandler, I want to override the default errorhandler(code) method without touching/creating base classes of Flask. How can i do this? please help    Thanks in advance

Comment: Which errors are you referring to?

Comment: I am not facing any errors wanting to implement above idea

Comment: Which error handlers are you referring to?

Comment: not only specific to error handler any method which belongs to object, its only Eg scenario

Comment: If all you want to do is override a method, just search.  There are lots of ways to do this.

Comment: Yeah i know but i have only app object with me how can i do that with out creating subclass to ''from parent.mywebapp.flaskutil import Flask', wanted to make change only in run.py

Comment: I think we have only mocking option to do that is there any approach?